# RemoteApp isn't working

Tags: rdp, remoteapp, rdc

Today I got bit with an issue with published applications (via RemoteApp). Clients were complaining about RDP.

You could connect to the server, run the application from there, but you could not run the application that has been published by RemoteApp.

I have checked everything but updates that came last night... so it took us like hours to find out what is going on. So for those you are using Windows Server 2008, and have problems with the published apps (via RemoteApp) get rid of " Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3004394)" which came 10.12.2014 and apps should be running smoothly.

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for your contribution. I see two problems however: First, [SF] is a Q&A site, problems should be answered in question and answer pairs. Thus, you should post the fix you found as a separate answer because otherwise people won't notice it. This brings me to the second problem: Your answer lacks detail. Can you offer additional insight into this?

Comment: Gordon, please see this stackoverflow link. i think i am having the same issue since this morning! It has to do with the updates that came recently from microsoft! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397870/rds-remoteapp-logged-off-immediately-after-preparing-desktop-under-details-msi

Comment: @Peter: Yes, the OP is aware of this, he just didn't post his knowledge as an answer, put it in the question instead. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Same problem and solved indeed with deleting KB3004394

Comment: Gordon:  What Sven said.  I think this post is really useful, but people aren't going to notice the fix because it's embedded in the question, and the site style is to have the Q and A separate.  If you self-answer--which is totally a thing--you could get more points, too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to remove this update and reboot affected server.

But it didn't immediately work.. let me explain:

a couple things to note:

1. Immediately upon reboot, same issue remained (oh crap)
2. Decided to remove same KB from guest computer and rebooted
3. Upon reboot, same issue remained
4. While researching issue further, about 10 minutes lapsed and i decided to try it again and it worked.

I can't explain the delay in it working, but I was able to resolve it with just that one KB removal.